# How to clean Mac OS X before selling (Lion from App Store)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have MacBook Pro (late 2007) which I planning to sell. Currently it's running Lion. Is it possible to clean all data but leave Lion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Just hold down <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during startup and Lion Recovery springs into action; It lets you choose from common utilities: You can choose to erase your hard drive and reinstall a fresh copy of Lion.

P.S: In order to reinstall OS X Lion, you will need to be connected to an Ethernet or Wi-Fi network

Comment: Note that you need to choose disk utility and erase the disc, not just "reinstall lion", which will try to fix a broken system but leave your files intact.